# How to demonstrate a particular functional equation solution

Tags: probability-distributions, functional-equations

In order to find a prior probability distribution I have to solve the following functional equation:

$$af\left(\frac{a\theta}{1-\theta-a\theta}\right)=(1-\theta+a\theta)^2f(\theta)$$

the solution of this equation must be a function $f(\theta)$.

I am new to functional equations, and my question is: could someone demonstrate me that 
$$f(\theta)=A \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{a-1}$$
is a solution of this equation?

EDIT:
I asked to my university teacher and he said that the problem was badly posed. We have that for $a=0$ the function $f(\theta)=\frac{A}{ \theta(1-\theta)}$ is a solution of the previous functional eq. (the demonstration is easy).

Then $f(\theta)=A \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{a-1}$ is a "generalization of the solution".

So a better question is, given that $f(\theta)=A \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{a-1}$ is a solution of the previous functional eq. for $a=0$ , are there values of $a\neq0$ for which this function is still a solution?

Comment: Do you have any information about the domain of $f$? Because e.g. for $\theta = 1$ the equation is *not* satisfied hence $f$ is not a solution to the functional equation.

Comment: $\theta$ is a probability, so $0\leq\theta\leq 1$

Comment: I might be a bit dumb here, but can I ask where did you get your solution? If it were a solution you'd expect it to hold for any value of $a$? If you e.g. evaluate the equation for $\theta = 1/2$, you don't get an identity, but rather an equation for $a$

Comment: Any conditions on a? Because $\theta = 0$ => a*f(0)=f(0)

=> Either a=1 or f(0)=0, it has its importance I think
And what is the domain of definition of your function f? Because we have to check, relatively to the left part of your equality, that it fits it

Comment: I am beating my head against this wall since this morning. A condition on $a$ would be most welcome. For $a \in [0, 1)$ there will be a second fixed point on $(0,1]$ of the inner function of $f$ on the LHS, which e.g. might imply another zero of $f$ there.

Comment: I am sorry, the problem was badly posed. See my edits

Comment: $ a = 1 $ works, as any constant function satisfies the functional equation in that case, and the function you're interested in will be constant for $ a = 1 $. But $ a = 0 $ does not work (opposite to what you've claimed), as the left-hand side of the functional equation becomes constant and the right-hand side nonconstant (unless $ A = 0 $).